# How to set scope or context for events

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set scope for some relatively simple events, but I can't make it work. I think I need to use `$(this)` or `event.currentTarget` but I don't know how.

I have these two events:

```
  $('.star').on('mouseover', function() {
    var indexAtual = $('.star').index(this);
    for (var i = 0; i <= indexAtual; i++) {
      $('.star:eq(' + i + ')').addClass('full');
    }
  });

  $('.star').on('mouseout', function() {
    $('.star').removeClass('full');
  });
```

The issue is that they should only be triggered for the actual element that is calling the event.

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9famoyxz/16/). How can I make the events work only for the individual element in question and not all of them?

Example - the html below is repeated several times:

```
<div class="bar">
  <span class="bg" style="width: 64%;"></span>
  <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1">
        <span class="starimg"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="2">
        <span class="starimg"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="3">
        <span class="starimg"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="4">
        <span class="starimg"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="5">
        <span class="starimg"></span>
      </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I tried with:

```
  $('.star').on('mouseover', function() {
    var indexAtual = $(this).index(this);
    for (var i = 0; i <= indexAtual; i++) {
      $(this).eq(i).addClass('full');
    }
  });
```

But it didn't give the same result...

Comment: `$(this)` inside of your event handler refers to the element that triggered the event element(most of the time) so example `$('this').removeClass('full');`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I updated my question with what I tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of your loop and use `.prevAll()` combined with `this` to do what you want:

```js
$('.star').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).prevAll().addBack().addClass('full');
});
$('.star').on('mouseout', function() {
  $('.star').removeClass('full');
});
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 110px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #ebebeb;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.bar .bg {
  float: left;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fee24f, #f4bb2f);
}

.bar .stars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar .star {
  float: left;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.bar .star.full {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fee24f, #f4bb2f);
}

.ratings * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ratings" data-item="4">
  <div class="bar">
    <span class="bg" style="width: 80%;"></span>
    <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="2">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="3">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="4">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="5">
          <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ratings" data-item="5">
  <div class="bar">
    <span class="bg" style="width: 32%;"></span>
    <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="2">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="3">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="4">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="5">
          <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ratings" data-item="3">
  <div class="bar">
    <span class="bg" style="width: 64%;"></span>
    <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="2">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="3">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="4">
         <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star" data-vote="5">
          <span class="starimg"></span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't even know .prevAll() or .addBack() Thanks for taking your time to fix this.